# Determining series convergence/divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{-3n(-3)^nx^n}{(n+1)\sqrt n} $$

For which real numbers $x$ does this series converge absolutely? converge conditionally? diverge?

How do I tackle these types of problems, where do I start?
All I noticed is that I could perhaps use L.A.S.T. to find values of $x$ such that the series converges conditionally.

Comment: need help on editing denominator meant to be square toot of n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Use [root test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) to obtain the condition $3|x|<1$ and then study the limit cases a part.